# Android não interpreta comando "\n" de uma página na web

Tags: php, android, return

Estou criando um app que ele acessa uma página URL, faz a consulta de alguns dados, e retorna o resultado em um *alert dialog*, porém no código da web, feito em PHP, preciso colocar alguns "\n"para formatar os dados, e tudo o que há antes do "\n" o Android não interpreta, ou seja, se o resultado tiver:

Resposta, "\n", resposta2, o Android consegue ler apenas o "resposta2", alguém teve o mesmo problema? Abaixo segue meu código Android que efetua a consulta e gera a resposta.

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());

writer.write("nome="+nomeProduto+"&aliquota="+aliquota+(laboratorio != null ? "&laboratorio="+laboratorio : ""));
writer.flush();

String line;

StringBuffer result=new StringBuffer();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        alertDialog.setMessage(line);
        alertDialog.setButton("Voltar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }});

        alertDialog.show();
}

writer.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: O problema é que está a fazer um `readLine()` que lê basicamente até encontrar '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim:

```
String result="";
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
     result += line;
}

alertDialog.setMessage(result);
alertDialog.setButton("Voltar",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }});
alertDialog.show();
```

Dessa forma vai ler todas as linhas.

Comment: Juarez, realmente ele reconheceu! porém no alert dialog ele le como se fosse um string de uma linha única, e no url de teste ele divide as linhas normalmente, é possível o android reconhecer exatamente como está na web ou tenho que ordenar os dados diretamente no celular?

Comment: Cara no android ele reconhece os `\n` talvez na leitura da linha ele nao le\descarta o `\n` então sugiro vc readicionar o `\n` da seguinte forma `result+=(line+"\n");`